# How to mix all colours in a JPG to a single colour in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have a grey floor tile with some colour texture. I want to mix all colours together so I get a single colour that I will paint my skirting board with. I intend to take a photo of the tile, mix it in gimp and when used to resulting colour to blend the paint.

I want this to mimic real paint blending. Imagine if every pixel in the image was a drop of paint, the paint colour will be all the drops mixed together.

Comment: Check out this question on the photo stack [How to calculate mean/average photo color in GIMP?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56160/how-to-calculate-mean-average-photo-color-in-gimp)

Answer (score 2):

`Filter>Blur>Pixellize` and give the same size as your image. This will replace the image by a single tile that has the same average color as your image. Sample it with the color picker to obtain the value.

You can also do a selection on your image, open the Histogram dock, and take the mean value for each channel.

Actual paint match depends on the screen calibration, and color balance accuracy in the initial image...

Answer (score 0):

1. use the Smudge Tool <kbd>S</kbd> to mix the colours together
2. use the Eyedropper <kbd>O</kbd> to sample a colour you like.
3. undo <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the changes.
4. use the Brush Tool <kbd>P</kbd> with the colour you selected.

[image]

Other methods are possible too, such as applying a strong Gaussian Blur to a selection. It's also possible to rescale an image to 1px x 1px, to get a single colour.